# JS update the value of the filtered object using array.filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I need to perform two actions 1) filter my array and 2) update the unfiltered values.
currently, I am doing it this way and it works fine.

```
let installData = state.installData.filter((item) => {
        return item.sensor !== action.data.sensor;
      });

      installData = installData.map((item) => {
        return { ...item, asOfDate: false };
      });
```

however, I am doing operations here and was wondering if there is a more efficient way to update the value of my item directly inside the filtred method without having to use map

Comment: Your operations seem fine, though you could chain them to avoid reassigning `installData`. `const installData = state.installData.filter((item) => ...).map((item) => ...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could just use `reduce` and combine operations into a single function

```
 let installData = state.installData.reduce((acc,item) => {
     if (item.sensor !== action.data.sensor) acc.push({...item, asOfDate: false});
     return acc;
  },[]);
```